# Terminal friendly output for IEx.Helper.h while outputting to something not TTY

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

Following this [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/command-line-shortcut-to-elixirs-help/4381/9) post, I created a shell script to view Elixir documentation by running `IEx.Helpers.h`:

```
elixir -e "require IEx.Helpers; IEx.Helpers.h($1)"
```

(where `$1` is the command line argument to the script). (For example, the command

```
elixir -e "require IEx.Helpers; IEx.Helpers.h(List)"
```

gives documentation for the module `List`.)

This is super nice. No need to run `iex` to view documentation anymore. Default formatting for terminal works nice and beautifully. But if I pipe the output to pager (or more generally, if the output is not a TTY device), the formatting changes - plain ASCII output without ANSI colors.

Question: how do I configure or direct `IEx.Helper.h` to provide identical output in the non-TTY case?

(It looks like there is function `IEx.configure` that can be used to change the formatting, but I could not see anything about non-TTY output. Another way would be to use some suitable miniscule external program to create a pseudo-TTY, redirecting `stdout` to that before running the `elixir` commmand... but I would prefer solving the output problem from Elixir side.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One might enforce colors no matter what output device is used by fooling [`IEx.Config.colors_enabled?/1`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7/lib/iex/lib/iex/config.ex#L62-L70) not to use a sophisticated check with `IO.ANSI.enabled?/0`:

```
elixir -e "
  Application.put_env(:iex, :colors, [enabled: true]);
  require IEx.Helpers;
  IEx.Helpers.h(List)"
```